# Tunnel HTTP traffic through a linux server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel

I want to tunnel data (HTTP / HTTPS) from one linux server through another to access proxies.

The reason I cannot go straight to the proxies is because they are all firewalled and I have far too many to whitelist. This is just a temporary setup to use the proxies.

So I want to go from `point A` to `points C, D & E` through `point B` (only B can access C, D & E). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify the browser, and the linux distribution

Comment: No browser running python scripts, point A is CentOS point B is Ubuntu.

Comment: For forwarding from any source, including from python scripts, make a SSH tunnel from localhost ports 80 and 443 to your middle server.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `simpleproxy` program to pass any TCP traffic coming to one port on your pass-through server to a certain other host:port. Then on the client machine change the proxy settings in your browser to use the pass-through server.

Simpleproxy can be installed using apt-get on debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install simpleproxy
```

Example of `simpleproxy` synopsis is as follows, but look up `man simpleproxy` for more details:

```
simpleproxy  -L [<local host>:]<local port> -R <remote host>:<remote port> -S <proxy host>:<proxy port>
```

Comment: I use `simpleproxy` for exactly this purpose. On my "relay" machine that proxies the requests ("B" in the question), I run `simpleproxy -L 7701 -R destination.example.com:80` to proxy requests to the relay on port 7701 to destination.example.com on port 80. If you need HTTPS, use `-S` instead of `-R` and port 443 instead of 80, of course

Answer (score 2):

If the linux box has an ssh server, you can simply use an ssh tunnel to proxy http.

If the client is running Linux, run:

```
ssh -D 8080 user@linux_ssh_server
```

This will open port 8080 on the local host, and make it behave like a socks proxy, making everything sent to that port appear as if it was sent by the proxy. Set up localhost:8080 as a socks5 proxy in your browser and you're done.

On windows, the same can be achieved with [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (see tutorial [here](http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/03/15/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty/))